# Facebook deep link do not opens Google Play when APP not installed

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an Android application with Facebook login and sharing, and also deep linking.
When the user have the APP installed, everything goes well:

1. Facebook login/logout
2. Share a link with Share Dialog (Feed Dialog when FB app is not installed)
3. Launch the APP with AppLinkData when clicking the news feed shared from this APP

However when the APP is not installed, the news feed just open the shared link with browser.
But I want is the news feed shared from the APP can send people to the APP's Google Play page.
Can anyone give me some hints? Thanks in advance!!

Here is want I have done for the application:

1. I created a New App in Facebook developer page. I enabled **Single Sign On** & **Deep Linking** in Setting page
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/KM9tn.png
2. I added custom URL scheme in AndroidManifest.xml

I've read the *Linking to your app from news feed* section from Facebook below:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share#applinks

Saying when a person clicks on a story generating by the APP, Facebook will check **App installed?** and **Mobile Only?**.

How can I set **Mobile Only** for my Android application?

I would greatly appreciate it if you kindly give me some feedback.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Deeplinks do not come with an automatic fallback. If a user clicks one and does not have the app installed, then they will either see a blank page or an error message.

If you want your deep links to redirect to the Google Play Store, you can set up fallbacks using Facebook’s App Links protocol on your website. In this case the fallback would be the Google Play store. According to App Links, Facebook should respect that protocol and fall back to the Google Play Store.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share#linking

Comment: Thanks for reply.

Setting up fallbacks mean adding metadata to the <head> tag?

I've added the followings, but no luck. It does not bring me to Google Play if the APP is not installed.


<head>

    ...

    <meta property="al:android:url" content="market://details?id=[myPackage]">

    <meta property="al:android:package" content="[myPackage]">

    <meta property="al:android:app_name" content="[myAppName]">

    ...

</head>

Comment: how did you solve your problem i am also stuck in this